# Get an error when deploy magento2

Tags: magento2, installation, apache2, static-content-deploy

When I generate static files in the deployment, I run 
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` but it fails.
 I have disabled the `extension=php_intl.dll` 
 in `etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` and restarted the apache webserver, but the issue is still popping up.

> jordan@jordan-Precision-M4600:/var/www/html/lightrabbit2$ php
>   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 cache_dir
>   "/var/www/html/lightrabbit2/var/page_cache" is not writable
>   jordan@jordan-Precision-M4600:/var/www/html/lightrabbit2$

Answer (score 0):

Please check your permissions for

> "/var/www/html/lightrabbit2/var/page_cache"

Answer (score 0):

The Intl Extension is [required by Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html). You should install it to solve the problem.

In addition to that, you should fix your permissions as recommended by Magento. For a shared hosting, use the following command in your root Magento dir.

```
find app/code pub/static app/etc var/generation var/di var/view_preprocessed vendor \( -type f -or -type d \) -exec chmod u-w {} \; && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php && chmod u+x bin/magento

chmod -R u+w .
```

For more information, read the [Magento 2 DevDocs for Permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html).